# What happens when the user leaves the app in the middle of a function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

Trying to understand a bit more about the Android lifecycle.

Consider 3 functions:

```
MyFragment(): Fragment(){

    private fun something(){
        // stuff
        **user leaves app**
        // more stuff
    }

    override onPause(){
        // stuff 
    }

    override onStop(){
        // stuff 
    }
```

If the user leaves the app in the middle of `something()` - will the 2nd part of the function get executed?

Comment: Activity lifecycle changes occur only on the UI thread. Therefore, if your `something` method is executing on the UI thread, `onStop`, `onDestroy` etc cannot be called until `something` is done. Now, if you block the UI thread for too long you risk causing an ANR or just making your app feel unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a pretty good question.

We have to look into that through a very important perspective,  when was function `something` called.

The way I understand from reading the android docs throughly is that, if you attempt to `finish` the activity from one of the startup callbacks, the activity will finish the opposing callback, after it is called, here is a thorough example about what am saying.

Let us say `something` is called in `onCreate`, and in the same callback you have called `finish`, after `onCreate` finishes execution, `onPause`, `onStop` will not be called, but rather `onDestroy` immediately.

If you do the same in `onStart`, `onStop` will be called immediately without `onPause` and then `onDestroy` accordingly.

Here are also some snippets from a log I written to prove my theory.

```
companion object {
    const val TAG = "LCTest"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Log.d(TAG, "Here is some code executed in OnCreate")
    finish()
    Log.d(TAG, "Here is some more code executed in OnCreate")
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d(TAG, "OnStart Called")
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Log.d(TAG, "OnResume Called")
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    Log.d(TAG, "OnPause Called")
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    Log.d(TAG, "OnStop Called")
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy Called")
}

override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()
    Log.d(TAG, "OnRestart Called")
}
```

The log resulted in the following:

```
D/LCTest: Here is some code executed in OnCreate
D/LCTest: Here is some more code executed in OnCreate
D/LCTest: OnDestroy Called
```

Doing the same in `OnStop` instead of `OnCreate` results in the following:

```
D/LCTest: OnCreate Called
D/LCTest: Here is some code executed in OnStart
D/LCTest: Here is some more code executed in OnStart
D/LCTest: OnStop Called
D/LCTest: OnDestroy Called
```

**Update**
If you mean some heavy operation by a regular function, I think that would block your main thread, and in that case you will have to move your function to a background thread, for example use Asynctask or a Couroutine. In that case when you exit the app, the thread will continue to work as long as the app process is still running, if you kill the app entirely and the function was executing still, surely it won't finish.

Hope this clears the confusion you had.

Comment: That clears up the execution of the lifecycle functions - however I think it would be good to add a regular function to your snippet too?

Comment: If you mean some heavy operation by a regular function, I think that would block your main thread, and in that case you will have to move your function to a background thread, for example use Asynctask or a couroutine. 

In that case when you exit the app, the thread will continue to work as long as the app process is still running, if you kill the app entirely and the function was executing still, surely it won't finish.

Answer (score 0):

android lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()` run in single thread called `MainThread`.

Therefore finish event must be added MainThread's event queue too. And it couldn't be executed if other executions in front of queue had been not complete.

In short, `more stuff` in your `something()` would be called.

Comment: Great. What if `something()` calls another function at the end of it? Would that also be called? (I assume it would because it's also on the MainThread) - but surely you have to draw the line somewhere?

Comment: Yes, every function on the main thread runs until it returns. If they call other functions, then those functions are part of the call stack and must return for the "top level" function to return. There's no "drawing the line". Functions cannot be interrupted unless they explicitly check for Thread.interrupted and explicitly 
 return (but I don't think Android tries to interrupt the main thread when finishing an Activity). Presumably, you're not calling any long-running functions on the Main Thread, because that's a big no-no.